# Sorting attributes are not working Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, elasticsearch, php-7.2, product-sorting

I'm trying to apply sorting from the toolbar on listing page, but none of the sorting properties like price, new, name etc. are working.

[image]

As you can see I have applied sort by price, but it's not sorting it by price same comes with other sorting options also.

Note: **I'm using elasticsuite 2.8.3 and Magento 2.3.3**

Comment: are you using any 3rd party exts. or added new options using customization in sorting dropdown? Try to install/upgrade the ES version to 5+ or 6+ on a webserver.

Comment: Yes I'm using 3rd party extension. Actually it's working on my local environment but not on my server. I was debugging it whole day but didn't found any solutions. I tried changing elasticseach versions also but didn't worked.

Comment: I have posted the reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will help you in some way as you suggest its working in your local but not on a server so better to go through points. If an issue from the code level then it may not help you further.**

1. Find Elastic Search Version hosted on the webserver?

   Via Web Open URL in web - **http://www.exampledomain.com:9200**

   OR

   Logged into the server and run - `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'`

   confirm the `version : { number : "X.X.X" }`
2. Which ES versions supported by 3rd Party Vendor (Smile/Wyomind/Amasty etc...)?

   As in your case, it is **2.8.x** so the same ES version should be there on the 
   webserver.

   If 3rd Party support 5.x or 6.x then it would be worth to use the upgrade version of ElasticSearch
3. At Magento end, Select the Catalog Search Engine under **System Configuration -> Catalog**.

   Be aware, **Test Connection** button only checks the connection, not the Elastic Search Version.

Comment: Thanks! elasticsearch version running on my staging was not the same as local that's why problem this problem arose.